# Encoding problem when adding text to existing PDF with CombinePDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, encoding, ruby-on-rails-6

(Rails 6.0.2.2, ruby 2.7.1, combine_pdf 1.0.18)

I'm currently trying to write some text to an existing PDF with the CombinePDF gem. Unfortunately I'm running in some encoding problems.

I'm loading the existing PDF:

```
pdf = CombinePDF.load "#{Rails.root}/public/pdf/base.pdf"
```

Then I'm adding text to it:

```
pdf.pages[0].textbox "Straße", height: 20, width: 160, y: 527, x: 215, font_size: 12, box_color: nil, text_align: :left, text_padding: 0
```

When generating a new pdf out of it:

```
send_data pdf.to_pdf, filename: "output.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
```

the string gets displayed as `StraˆŸe`, so the `ß` isn't displayed correctly.

I also tried to replace it with unicode literals (`\xc3\x9f`) without any effect.

Anybody has an idea what else to try?

Comment: Are you set on using CombinePDF? If not, have you tried prawn+prawn-template or HexaPDF? The issue probably stems from CombinePDF not implementing enough of the PDF specification.

Comment: Not set on CombinePDF. I tried prawn-template but the page with template ends up empty. I will give HexaPDF angry.

Answer (score -1):

If you use [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) you could do something like this:

```rb
require 'hexapdf'
require 'stringio'

doc = HexaPDF::Document.open("#{Rails.root}/public/pdf/base.pdf")
doc.pages[0].canvas.font("Helvetica", size: 12).text("Straße", at: [215, 527])
outio = StringIO.new(''.b)
doc.write(outio)
```

Just make sure that you use a font that contains glyphs for all characters you want to use. So better use a TrueType font instead of the builtin Helvetica (you can just provide the path to a TrueType font to the `#font` method).